# SendGrid requires credentials for every login using WP

Tags: civimail, extension

Just move our site to a new hosting environment. Did not have this problem before.  Using CiviCRM with WordPress.  Every time we go into CiviCRM we must enter the SendGrid credentials.  Any idea what would cause this and how to stop it?

Update: This problem came back. It is an authentication login and it is required. It is part of the Sendgrid plugin for CiviCRM. Wrote to the developer who tells me that this plugin is incorrectly listed as CRM independent - it only works 'properly' with drupal.

The authentication is required for any access to civicrm, including public listing or event registration, etc. Hence Sendgrid Plugin is not viable for WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

This is resolved on its own, not sure why or how but this is no longer happening.  If I find more info I will post for anyone else with the same problem.

Update: This problem came back.  It is an authentication login and it is required. It is part of the Sendgrid plugin for CiviCRM. Wrote to the developer who tells me that this plugin is incorrectly listed as CRM independent - it only works 'properly' with drupal.

The authentication is required for any access to civicrm, including public listing or event registration, etc. Hence Sendgrid Plugin is not viable for WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

With Reference to the update in your [answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/12602/52): "...Sendgrid Plugin is not viable for WordPress"

We have implemented SendGrid on a number of WP sites, the only problem we were finding was that Bounce Processing was not working. [Andrew Hunt](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/44/andrew-hunt) forked the extension and added code to make it work with WP (& Joomla I think). Forked extension can be found at: https://github.com/agh1/com.imba.sendgrid - A pull request was made to the original extension, but I don't think it's been accepted yet.